# What is Laplace of $\cos t \log t \ \delta(t-π)$?

Tags: laplace-transform

I know the Laplace of $\delta(t-\pi)$. But I don't know how to find Laplace of $\cos t \log t \ \delta(t-π)$.

How can I find Laplace of $\cos t \log t \ \delta(t-\pi)$ ?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: Please, type in mathjax and provide context of the question

Comment: What have you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty\delta(t-c)f(t)dt=f(c)$$ the trick is to notice that $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty\delta(t-c)f(t)dt=\int_{c-\epsilon}^{c+\epsilon}\delta(t-c)f(t)dt$$ for $\epsilon>0$. If we can assume that $f(t)$ is continuous in the interval $(c-\epsilon,c+\epsilon)$, that is, for every $\eta>0$ there exists an $\epsilon$ such that $|f(t)-f(c)|<\eta$ whenever $|t-c|<\epsilon$, then $$\int_{c-\epsilon}^{c+\epsilon}\delta(t-c)f(t)dt=f(c)\int_{c-\epsilon}^{c+\epsilon}\delta(t-c)dt=f(c)$$ This tells you that $$\boxed{\mathcal L\{\delta(t-c)f(t)\}=f(c)e^{-cs}}$$

---

> In your case $f(t)=\cos(t)\log(t)\delta(t-\pi)$, with $c=\pi$. Thus $$\mathcal L\{\cos(t)\log(t)\delta(t-\pi)\}=-\log(\pi)e^{-\pi s}$$

Comment: I can get the answer of $cos t \ \delta(t - \pi)$  but what about $log t $

Comment: @VikeshPatil What did you do when working with $\cos(t)\delta(t-\pi)$? You should edit your question and include it, that way it becomes clear for everyone that you have made an attempt.

Comment: You corrected your mistake at the end!

Comment: @Axion004 I did, well spotted!

Comment: Nope my question was same just format was wrong. To correct it I had edited the question not to change it.

Comment: Okay. Got the answer. I have to consider $cos t log t$ as a single function $ f\(t\)$ and have to replace t with c

Comment: @VikeshPatil Well done!

Comment: Thank you everyone for your time